# how to use a composite key with the IN keyword in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to write the following (pseudo) SQL statement in MS Access:

```
Select C 
from MyTable
where (A, B) IN (select distinct A,B from MyTable);
```

I tried that but got the complaint "You have written a subquery that can return more than one field without using the EXISTS reserved word in the main query's FROM clause."

I appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Your query looks like your trying to do: `SELECT A, B, C FROM MyTable`, Can you provide your actual query please.

Comment: I don't think you can use a tuple for `in` like that - and Robert's got a good point: this will return all Cs from your table anyway.

Comment: You might need to include some sample data as well as the actual code. Even if the tuple worked, "Where (A,B) in (Select distinct A,B)" seems like it would match every record. Not sure what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an inner join as a filter:

```
select  c
from    MyTable t1
inner join
        (
        select  distinct
                a
        ,       b
        from    OtherTable
        ) t2
on      t1.a = t2.a
        and t1.b = t2.b
```

(I'm assuming you have two tables because the query doesn't make much sense for one table.  Obviously, all combinations of A and B that are in Table1 will "also" be in Table1.)